# ObservableCollection is not providing adding new row to the datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

this is my First WPF application, and i need some help
i have created a WPF Window that contains Datagrid binded to a database using EF, `CollectionViewSource`
when drag and drop a table from Data Sources Window on the Window the MDI Automatically generate a code

```
ObjectQuery<ITPORTAL.HRMS_IT_ASSET_MASTER> ass = gRACHRMSEntities.HRMS_IT_ASSET_MASTER;
```

And the object query assigned to CollectionViewSource.Source as follow

```
hRMS_IT_ASSET_MASTERQuery = Load_Asset_Master_Data(gRACHRMSEntities.HRMS_IT_ASSET_MASTER);
hRMS_IT_ASSET_MASTERViewSource.Source = hRMS_IT_ASSET_MASTERQuery.Execute(System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.AppendOnly);
```

But This code did't support Filtering Facility thats why I have add somthing like this

```
 private ObservableCollection<ITPORTAL.HRMS_IT_ASSET_MASTER> Load_Asset_Master_Data(System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<ITPORTAL.HRMS_IT_ASSET_MASTER> objectSet)
        {
            ObservableCollection<ITPORTAL.HRMS_IT_ASSET_MASTER> oc = null;
            try
            {
                var value = from Asset_Master in objectSet
                            where Asset_Master.IT_ASSET_IS_ACTIVE == "1" && Asset_Master.IT_ASSET_IS_SCRAPED == "0" && Asset_Master.IT_ASSET_IS_SCRAP_FINAL == "0"
                            select Asset_Master;
                oc = new ObservableCollection<HRMS_IT_ASSET_MASTER>(value.ToList());
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "IT Portal Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error, MessageBoxResult.OK);
            }
            return oc;
        }
```

And assigned to CollectionViewSource as follow

```
hRMS_IT_ASSET_MASTERViewSource.Source = Load_Asset_Master_Data(gRACHRMSEntities.HRMS_IT_ASSET_MASTER);
```

By this way I can do filtering
but i have lost one feature because
when i am filling the row at the end of the datagrid and press save
the Save command does not consider the added row,
the save command response only to editing actions
here is the Save event handler

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {                                               
                if (gRACHRMSEntities.SaveChanges() > 0)
                {
                    txtblkStatus.Text = "Changes has been saved.";                
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error, MessageBoxResult.OK);

        }       }
```

i have checked online and i found that 
When using an `ObservableCollection<T>` I will have to provide my own implementation for `IEditableObject` for T.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write

```
hRMS_IT_ASSET_MASTERViewSource.ItemsSource =Load_Asset_Mast ...
```

instead of:

```
hRMS_IT_ASSET_MASTERViewSource.Source =Load_Asset_Mast ...
```

I mean you should set ItemsSource .